# New kendo sheduler events don't call controller methods

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to add a new scheduler event to database. It's added to the scheduler datasource and its visible in scheduler, but isn't call controller Create method. 
Edit or delete newly added event also don't call controller methods, but change datasource.

Already exists events work well.

Model:

```
public class ResourceSchedulerModel : ISchedulerEvent
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
    public string EndTimezone { get; set; }
    public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
    public int BTS_Id { get; set; }

    public ResourceSchedulerModel() { }

    public ResourceSchedulerModel(BusyTimeSlot bts)
    {
        BTS_Id = bts.BTS_Id;
        Start = bts.BTS_From;
        End = bts.BTS_To;
        Title = bts.BTS_Name;
        Description = bts.BTS_Description;
        ResId = bts.BTS_RES_Id;
    }
}
```

Controller methods:

```
    public virtual JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        EntityWrapper ew = new EntityWrapper();
        List<BusyTimeSlot> btss = ew.GetAllBusyTimeSlots();
        List<ResourceSchedulerModel> sm = new List<ResourceSchedulerModel>();
        foreach (BusyTimeSlot b in btss)
            sm.Add(new ResourceSchedulerModel(b));
        return Json(sm.ToDataSourceResult(request));

    }

    public virtual JsonResult Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ResourceSchedulerModel task)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // delete
        }

        return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    public virtual JsonResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ResourceSchedulerModel task)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //add
            }

            return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    public virtual JsonResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ResourceSchedulerModel task)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // edit
        }

        return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<SchedulerTry.Models.ResourceSchedulerModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(new DateTime(2014, 10, 11))
    .MinorTickCount(1)
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView();
        views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
        views.MonthView();
        views.AgendaView();
    })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m => {
            m.Id(f => f.BTS_Id);
            m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
        })
        .Read("Read", "Resource")
        .Create("Create", "Resource")
        .Destroy("Destroy", "Resource")
        .Update("Update", "Resource")
    )

)
```

In addition, when I try close or cancel the edit window of new event I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BTS_Id' of undefined kendo.all.min.js:11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I have another Create method in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the BTS_Id as below intialization as below:

```
    public int bTS_Id;
    public string BTS_Id 
    {
        get
        {
            return bTS_Id;
        }
        set
        {
            bTS_Id = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not working. New events still don't work, and old ones when update throw internal server error.
btw your code need convert.